# jQuery Event Handler not working after body load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does my event only work within a setInterval? I've tried several ways and it never works, only within a setinterval

```
var buttonsub = setInterval(function() {
    
    if($('#continue_button').length && $('.content-box__row.ship_step_wait').length == 0){
        console.log('continue');
        
        var myvar = '<button name="button" id="send_button" class="btn" style="width: 100%;"><span class="btn__content" data-continue-button-content="true">Complete order</span><svg class="icon-svg icon-svg--size-18 btn__spinner icon-svg--spinner-button" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <use xlink:href="#spinner-button"></use> </svg></button>';
        $("#continue_button").prop("type", "button");
        
        
        $("#continue_button").click(function(e){
            formSend();
            return false;
        });
        
        clearInterval(buttonsub);
    }
}, 800); // check every 100ms
```

Comment: Tried to load it in `$(document).ready(...)` ?

Comment: Is there a comparison value missing here: `$('#continue_button').length`?

Comment: @PanwenWang, not working, ready, load

Comment: @CriticalError It's equivalent to `$('#continue_button').length != 0`

Comment: Are the elements that you're looking for added asynchronously, e.g. with AJAX?

Comment: One possibility is that `#continue_button` doesn't exist when doc is loaded, it is added sometime later.

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the original click event, but the setInterval does.

Try adding this in the head of your document.

```
<script>

    $( function () {

        // Assign initial click event to #continue_button.
        $( '#continue_button' ).click( function (e) {

            if( $( '#continue_button' ).length && $( '.content-box__row.ship_step_wait' ).length == 0 ) 
            {
            
                console.log('continue');

                var myvar = '<button name="button" id="send_button" class="btn" style="width: 100%;"><span class="btn__content" data-continue-button-content="true">Complete order</span><svg class="icon-svg icon-svg--size-18 btn__spinner icon-svg--spinner-button" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <use xlink:href="#spinner-button"></use> </svg></button>';
                $( '#continue_button' ).prop( 'type', 'button' );

                $( '#continue_button' ).click(function(e) {
                    formSend();
                    return false;
                });

            };

        } );

    } );

</script>
```

Comment: @LucianoMallmann there is some definite cleanup that can be done inside my example, but I wanted to keep it in line with your initial question.